# Sorting data frame by character string

Tags: r, string, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame and need to sort its columns by a character string.

I tried it like this:

```
  # character string
  a <- c("B", "E", "A", "D", "C")

  # data frame
  data <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 1), B = c(1, 1, 1), C = c(1, 0, 1), D = c(0, 0, 1), E = c(0, 1, 1))
  data
  # A B C D E
  # 1 0 1 1 0 0
  # 2 0 1 0 0 1
  # 3 1 1 1 1 1

  # sorting 
  data.sorted <- data[, order(a)]

  # order of characters in data
  colnames(data.sorted)
  # [1] "C" "A" "E" "D" "B"
```

However, the order of columns in the sorted data frame is not the same as the characters in the original character string.

Is there any way, how to sort it?

Answer (score 3):

The function `order(a)` returns the position in the vector `a` that each ranked value lies in. So, since "A" (ranked first) lies in the third position of `a`, `a[1]` is equal to 3. Similarly "C" (ranked third) lies in the fifth position of `a`, then `a[3]` equals 5.

Luckily your solution is actually even more simple, thanks to the way `R` works with brackets. If you ask to see just the column named "B" you'll get:

```
> data[, "B", drop=FALSE]
  B
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

Or if you want two specific columns

```
> data[, c("B", "E")]
  B E
1 1 0
2 1 1
3 1 1
```

And finally, more generally, if you have a whole vector by which you want to order your columns, then you can do that, too:

```
> data.sorted <- data[, a]

> data.sorted
  B E A D C
1 1 0 0 0 1
2 1 1 0 0 0
3 1 1 1 1 1

> all(colnames(data.sorted)==a)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str = { "H", "G", "F", "D", "S","A" };
Array.Sort(str);
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str[i]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: FOR DESCENSING ADD Array.reverse();